# Tensorflow topn_test fails on ppc64le

Tags: tensorflow

With tensorflow 0.12, topn_test.py has failures for the tests written for TopN class on ppc64le.
Taking an example of one of the failing tests in it, here is what is being observed -

### FAIL: testSimple (**main**.TopNTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "./python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/topn_test.py", line 121, in testSimple
    self.assertItemsEqual([2, 3], list(ids_v))
AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
First has 1, Second has 0:  2
First has 0, Second has 1:  1
```

Expected is `[2, 3]` whereas actual is `[3, 1]`.

Code of this test is as below -

```
def testSimple(self):
    t = topn.TopN(1000, shortlist_size=10)
    t.insert([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
    t.remove([4, 5])
    ids, vals = t.get_best(2)
    with session.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        ids_v, vals_v = sess.run([ids, vals])
        self.assertItemsEqual([2, 3], list(ids_v))
        self.assertItemsEqual([2.0, 3.0], list(vals_v))
```

In above test, if we run ids into sess before `ids_v, vals_v = sess.run([ids, vals])`, then the test passes which means running ids into session twice gives expected result in 2nd run. 
The output of 1st sess.run(ids) gives `[3, 1]` and then next run gives `[3, 2]`. This is weird. Ideally sess.run should always give fixed result in every run. Please correct if I'm wrong here.

Same thing is observed even on x86, with the only difference is 1st run gives `[3, 2]` and 2nd run gives `[3, 3]`.

Could someone please tell me how sess.run(ids) gives different output in each run? Is this expected behavior or there is some other underlying problem with the implementation of TopN class? I've also checked with a constant tensor and this weird behavior is not seen with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This test case fails even on x86 with GPU, with the same actual output.